# How to achieve below scenario with sql

Tags: mysql, sql

The table structure

```
ID      Name    Cost
-------------------------
1       Peter   10
1       Peter   20
1       Peter   30
2       Lily    10
2       Lily    20
2       Lily    30
-------------------------
```

and I will like to achieve something as below for reporting

```
ID      Name    Cost
-------------------------
1       Peter   10
                20
                30
2       Lily    10
                20
                30
-------------------------
```

so what I have try is using left join but instead of giving me a results like above, it returns like this, exactly the same with the table structure.

```
ID      Name    Cost     No Column Name
--------------------------------------
1       Peter   10
1       Peter   20
1       Peter   30
2       Lily    10
2       Lily    20
2       Lily    30
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you share your attempts to achieve this with the errors / problems that these tests have conjured?

Comment: SQL deals in tables. You are looking for a report-formatting function that shows group headers.

Comment: I did tried using `WITH` to create temp table and join together and it returns like the last table structure. @CanO'Spam

Comment: Yea since crystal report make take ages to organize data so I want to try grouping it with store procedure first. @O.Jones

Comment: Yeah, no doubt. Enterprise software is expensive. That's OK though, because it's also slow and hard to use.  :-)

Comment: @AlexDe - you need to share your attempts, without this we are stabbing in the dark fixing what we can't see. We need your queries

Answer (score 2):

More of an expanded comment than an answer.  Not properly tested or sure is the best method

```
select 
case q.R when 1 then cast(q.id as nvarchar) else '' end as _id,
case q.r when 1 then q.nm else '' end as _nm,
q.cost
from
(
select 
p.id,p.nm,p.cost,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by p.id order by p.cost) as R
from tpeople as p
) as q
order by q.id
```