# Is there a way to return a partial blank row in SQL when joining tables through automation?

Tags: sql

For my project, I have 2 tables. Initially I inner joined both tables (table 1 and 2) via an inner join. However, I wanted an outcome as seen in table 4 where the repeated value from table 1 is left blank instead.

For table 2, the number of rows will always vary. There will always only be 1 department ID attached to numerous function IDs. Is there a query then where regardless of the number of function IDs, the department ID will only appear as the first row as seen in table 4?

(I think to many, this might seem weird and frankly not clean data, but for mail merges within word, it is easier to field code when the data is presented this way to refrain sections from 'reprinting itself'.)

Current Code:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.* FROM
INNER JOIN Table 2 ON Table1.DepartmentID = Table2.DepartmentID
```

Table 1:

| Department ID | Department |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | XYZ |

Table 2:

| Department ID | Function ID | Function |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ABC |
| 1 | 2 | DEF |

Table 3 (inner joined):

| Department ID | Department | FunctionID | Function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XYZ | 1 | ABC |
| 1 | XYZ | 2 | DEF |

Table 4 (desired):

| Department ID | Department | FunctionID | Function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XYZ | 1 | ABC |
|  |  | 2 | DEF |

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you; it makes it harder to. Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer. It can also easily end up attracting downvotes and also close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about. I have removed the conflicting tags; [edit] your question and retag appropriately.

Comment: You could use `LEAD` or `LAG`; though I feel this is more something for your presentation layer *not* the SQL layer.

Comment: Apologies for the tag issues, still learning how to use stack properly will take note of it in the future. For the lead, lag, I'll go look it up thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72099965/how-to-achieve-below-scenario-with-sql/72100194#72100194

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Hi! I wanted to followup on the link you sent, I wanted to ask how would you implement it here? Apologies, I'm still learning sql